# React Routing with URL Link as params

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-v4

How can i set route like this.

```
<Route path='/:id/:url' component={Url}/>
```

and then in Url component access the value of this url like.

```
const url = this.props.params.match.url
```

so if i pass in `http://localhost:3000/245/http://www.msn.com`

i would be able to get this url value through props.params.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can encode your URL to remove the slashes and other URL specific symbols using `encodeURIComponent`

So for your case, it'll be `const urlEncoded = encodeURIComponent(http://www.msn.com)` then passing this value to your URL should result to `http://localhost:3000/245/http%3A%2F%2Fwww.msn.com` which you can access using `this.props.params.match.url`

Answer (score 0):

All you need is encode URI for passing url in query string.

you can use encodeURIComponent() to encode URL and decodeURIComponent() to retrive back in url format

And then you can access it using this.props.params.match.url

```
const url = encodeURIComponent(this.props.params.match.url)
```

Comment: Yes got it. Thanks for your help.